# How to merge multiple XML entries into one tree with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML that I'm trying to restructure with XSL. I am quite new to XSL so any help would be appreciated.

My current XML is currently given to me like this.

```
<catalogItem>
  <partNumber>114-0015</partNumber>
  <itemName>This is Item 1</itemName>
  <price>$5.69</price>
</catalogItem>
<catalogItem>
  <partNumber>114-0016</partNumber>
  <itemName>This is Sub-item1</itemName>
  <price>$6.29</price>
  <parent>114-0015</parent>
</catalogItem>
<catalogItem>
  <partNumber>114-0017</partNumber>
  <itemName>This is Sub-item2</itemName>
  <price>$7.29</price>
  <parent>114-0015</parent>
</catalogItem>
<catalogItem>
  <partNumber>114-0018</partNumber>
  <itemName>This is Sub-item3</itemName>
  <price>$8.29</price>
  <parent>114-0015</parent>
</catalogItem>
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to restructure it so that any catalogItem with a parent tag would get inserted into an xml tree structure. Note that the parent tag corresponds with the partNumber of that items parent. So my final output would be:

```
<catalogItem>
  <partNumber>114-0015</partNumber>
  <itemName>This is Item 1</itemName>
  <price>$5.69</price>
  <subitem>
    <subPartNumber>114-0016</subPartNumber>
    <subItemName>This is Sub-item1</subItemName>
    <subPrice>$6.29</subPrice>
  </subitem>
  <subitem>
    <subPartNumber>114-0017</subPartNumber>
    <subItemName>This is Sub-item2</subItemName>
    <subPrice>$7.29</subPrice>
  </subitem>
  <subitem>
    <subPartNumber>114-0018</subPartNumber>
    <subItemName>This is Sub-item3</subItemName>
    <subPrice>$8.29</subPrice>
  </subitem>
</catalogItem>
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction (hopefully provide some code samples) that would help me out.
Thanks!

EDIT: I am also including my current xslt that I'm using to do some other transformations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
<dataroot>
  <xsl:for-each select="dataroot/catalogItem">
    <catalogItem>
    <xsl:if test="not(partNumber)"><Intro>
      <xsl:if test="not(partNumber)"><itemNameIntro><xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></itemNameIntro></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not(partNumber)"><longDescriptionIntro><xsl:value-of select="longDescription"/></longDescriptionIntro></xsl:if>
      </Intro></xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="photo1"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="categoryType"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="bookSeries"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="photo2"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="photo3"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="photo4"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="logo"/>
      <xsl:if test="partNumber"><itemName><xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></itemName></xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="author"/>
      <xsl:if test="partNumber"><longDescription><xsl:value-of select="longDescription"/></longDescription></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="size1">
        <size1><xsl:value-of select="size1"/><xsl:if test="size1 and size2"> | </xsl:if></size1>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="size2"/>
      <xsl:if test="age">
        <age><xsl:if test="size1 and age or size2 and age"> | </xsl:if>age: <xsl:value-of select="age"/></age>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="numberPages">
        <numberPages><xsl:value-of select="numberPages"/>p </numberPages>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="partNumber"/>
      <xsl:if test="price">
        <pricetab>  $</pricetab>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="price">
        <price><xsl:value-of select="price"/></price>
      </xsl:if>
    </catalogItem>
  </xsl:for-each>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: As the `catalogItem` with `<partNumber>114-0018</partNumber>` has `<parent>114-0016</parent>`, I don't understand the result you have posted.

Comment: My bad. I fixed it. It was supposed to be 114-0015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "current XML" is not XML at all, as it has no single root element.

Given a well-formed XML input such as:

```
<catalog>
  <catalogItem>
    <partNumber>114-0015</partNumber>
    <itemName>This is Item 1</itemName>
    <price>$5.69</price>
  </catalogItem>
  <catalogItem>
    <partNumber>114-0016</partNumber>
    <itemName>This is Sub-item1</itemName>
    <price>$6.29</price>
    <parent>114-0015</parent>
  </catalogItem>
  <catalogItem>
    <partNumber>114-0017</partNumber>
    <itemName>This is Sub-item2</itemName>
    <price>$7.29</price>
    <parent>114-0015</parent>
  </catalogItem>
  <catalogItem>
    <partNumber>114-0018</partNumber>
    <itemName>This is Sub-item3</itemName>
    <price>$8.29</price>
    <parent>114-0015</parent>
  </catalogItem>
</catalog>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="catalogItem" use="parent" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="catalogItem[not(parent)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalogItem">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', partNumber)" mode="sub"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalogItem" mode="sub">
    <subitem>
    <subPartNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="partNumber"/>
    </subPartNumber>
    <subItemName>
        <xsl:value-of select="itemName"/>   
    </subItemName>
    <subPrice>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>  
    </subPrice>
    </subitem>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <catalogItem>
      <partNumber>114-0015</partNumber>
      <itemName>This is Item 1</itemName>
      <price>$5.69</price>
      <subitem>
         <subPartNumber>114-0016</subPartNumber>
         <subItemName>This is Sub-item1</subItemName>
         <subPrice>$6.29</subPrice>
      </subitem>
      <subitem>
         <subPartNumber>114-0017</subPartNumber>
         <subItemName>This is Sub-item2</subItemName>
         <subPrice>$7.29</subPrice>
      </subitem>
      <subitem>
         <subPartNumber>114-0018</subPartNumber>
         <subItemName>This is Sub-item3</subItemName>
         <subPrice>$8.29</subPrice>
      </subitem>
   </catalogItem>
</catalog>
```

Comment: sorry. I should have included my root element. I do have it. I just hadn't included it for this sample.

Comment: @user6621322 Is your question answered?

Comment: am trying to work it in to my xml here. Will let you know once I've got it sorted out here.

Comment: Ok. so thanks for your examples. however, since I don't really have a huge understanding of what's going on I was not able to figure out how to work it into my existing xslt. I editted my original question to include that. could you explain how to fit that in my existing xslt? Thanks!

Comment: Also just to clarify. my current xslt includes transformations for some data that I didn't show in my sample xml just because I wanted to keep it simple so sorry if it adds to the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to write your code for you. I couldn't do that even if I wanted to, because your XSLT does not match your input example. I believe this question was about nesting child elements into their parents - and I think I have answered that. You are welcome to post additional questions with any specific problems you run into.

Comment: I am new to xslt and unfortunately since I don't really understand what each part does it didn't exactly answer my question. Thanks for trying tho

Comment: I believe this is getting me close enough for now. Thanks